# The Handle Is Invalid with ManualResetEvent.Set()

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, handle

I have a strange problem with the method Set() in a ManualResetEvent object. 
I have created a library embedding a DLL COM object used to communicate with a machine.

Before sending a message to the COM object (m_server object), I subscribe to CommandReceived event then I send the message (SendMessage method) and I wait for a response (WaitOne) from the COM object.

Once the event is raised, I notify the ManualResetEvent with Set() method. Sometimes, I get an exception “The Handle is Invalid.”.

Apparently, the ManualResetEvent uses an internal Handle. It would have been invalidated by the system for some reason.

This is the code:

```
using (ManualResetEvent msgResponseWait = new ManualResetEvent(false)) {

__RCServer_CommandReceivedEventHandler onCommandReceivedDlg = delegate(ref short isock, string sCommand) {
    try {
        if (MessageReceived != null) {
            MessageReceived(this, null);
        }
        ServerMessage receivedServerMessage = ServerMessage.Parse(sCommand);
        if (msg.Command == receivedServerMessage.Command && msg.GvLocation == receivedServerMessage.GvLocation) {
            msg.Value = receivedServerMessage.Value;
            msg.ReceivedResponseDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            msgResponseWait.Set();
        } else {
            m_logger.AddTrace(
                string.Format("Mismatch between request/response." + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Command sent: '{0}' / Command received: '{1}'" + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Location sent: '{2}' / Location received: '{3}'",
                                msg.Command, receivedServerMessage.Command,
                                msg.GvLocation, receivedServerMessage.GvLocation),
                ELogGroup.Equipment, ESeverityLog.Error);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        m_logger.AddErrHandler(e);
    }
};

m_server.CommandReceived += onCommandReceivedDlg;

msg.SendRequestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
m_server.SendMessage(ref iSocket, ref message);
if (!msgResponseWait.WaitOne(msg.TimeoutResponseInMillis)) {
    m_logger.AddTrace("No response received", ELogGroup.Equipment, ESeverityLog.Error);
    msg.TimeoutOccurred = true;
}

m_server.CommandReceived -= onCommandReceivedDlg;

msg.WaitResponse.Set();
```

}

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hard to see how it can ever work, the MRE is disposed by the *using* statement before the WaitOne() call.  msgResponseWait is a problem as well, if the timeout ever trips then the Set() call is doomed to fail if it was disposed.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but the Set() cannot be done because we have unsubscribed to the event CommandReceive. Is it possible that the unsubscription takes some time before it is really effective ?

Comment: Sure, it is a threading race.

Comment: When I see the log files, there is no trace of timeout before the exception "The handle is invalid".

Comment: In my log files I have:
1. 00:00 The handle is invalid
2. 00:02 No response received
Note: this method is executed each 2 seconds. There is no reason that we have a timeout after the first exception because it's a second call